# Matlab integration and abs

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

In MATLAB (R2017b, online version) I found an issue during symbolic integration: try to calculate integral of `f(t) = abs(sin(t))` . Due to the fact that `f(t)` is always positive, I expect that the integral in `[a, b]` is lower equal than the integral in `[a, b']` if `b < b'`. But:

```
int( abs(sin(t)), t, 0, pi )   -> 2 % OK
int( abs(sin(t)), t, 0, 2*pi ) -> 2 % NO (should be 4)
```

In fact, if we plot the function that represent the integral from `0` to `x`, which should be *monotonic*, we found something different:

```
% for each value x(i) of x we will calculate integral from 0 to x(i)
x = 0 : pi/8 : 4*pi;
% actual computation
Z = zeros(length(x), 1);                            % create array
syms t;                                             % create symbolic variable t
calculate_int = @(n) int(abs(sin(t)), t, 0, n);     % integral function
for i = 1 : length(Z)
    Z(i) = calculate_int(x(i));
end
% plot result
figure;
plot(x, Z);
```

results in this obviously *non monotonic* function:

[image: Plot]

Non symbolic integration gives no problem:

```
x = 0 : 0.01 : pi;
f = abs(sin(x));
value = sum(f * 0.01) % 2

x = 0 : 0.01 : 2 * pi;
f = abs(sin(x));
value = sum(f * 0.01) % 4
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the code properly? Because I've tried your code and this is what I got: https://imgur.com/eqY2Wme

Comment: @TommasoBelluzzo: I can replicate this perfectly in the desktop version of R2017b.

Comment: This appears to be specific to R2017b. I cannot replicate the issue in R2017a and earlier. Seems like a bug. I suggest that you [file a service request](https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/?s_tid=sp_ban_cs).

Comment: For my test I used 2017a <_<

Comment: [MuPAD's `int`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/int.html) appears to have the same issue. Workarounds include using `integral` or `vpaintegral` calculate this numerically or with variable precision arithmetic, respectively..

Comment: Thank you all. If someone wants to add an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: So, to summarize, R2017b **desktop** has the issue, but < R2017a **desktop** does not. However, as noted by the OP, the R2017a **online** version has the bug. I cannot replicate this on **desktop** versions R2017a, R2016a, R2014a, R2010a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bug in Matlab R2017b. See @horchler comments for details.